# Как хранится имя переменной?

Tags: c++, c, типы-данных

Помогите разобраться поглубже чем по сути является именованная ячейка памяти (переменная).
Не могу правильно сформулировать свой вопрос, но т.е понимаю, что при хранения данных в блоке памяти выделяется место, но не понимаю как хранится именованная ее часть.
К примеру:

```
int a = 5;
```

По сути начало блока памяти для числа `5` является первый его адрес, к примеру `0х0000132` но чем является переменная `а`? Его неким псевдонимом? Или блок памяти имеет кроме хранения значения еще и метаинформацию для хранения того же `а`?

Не хочу показаться тупым, но не может быть что `а` является ссылочным типом на `int`, который смотрит в этом случае на стек первого адреса значения `5`?

Comment: В с++ никак именованая часть не хранится. После компиляции остаются только адреса, но не имена.

Comment: Т.е это абстрактное представления и на этапе компиляции именованная часть улетает?

Comment: Вижу Вы поправили свой комментарий. Теперь стало все на свои места.
Спасибо

Comment: Да. При компиляции с++ получается набор команд процессора. А процессор оперирует адресами, но не именами.

Comment: Теперь стало еще проще о понимании темы указателей и адресной арифметики в целом ...

Comment: В таком случае я могу предполагать что L_VALUE всегда является абстрактным понятием и пониманием что происходит в программе, а R_VELUE его реализацией?

Comment: Не понял, о чем вы (от слова совсем)

Comment: Правое значения выражения является тем, что происходит в памяти, а левое значения выражение имеет то, как оно будет реализовано в памяти и результат всего выражения является его реализации во время рантайма?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На самом деле, **у переменной может не быть адреса вовсе**.

- Если переменная используется лишь на небольшом участке, компилятор может эту переменную затолкать в регистр процессора и держать её там в течение всего времени её жизни, не выделяя ей место в оперативной памяти вовсе.
- Если в программе используется лишь изначальное значение неменяющейся переменной, компилятор волен вставить вместо чтения этой переменной само значение. В качестве непосредственного (immediate) значения, прямо в генерируемый программный код.
- Если переменная вообще не оказывает никакого влияния на ход программы и не торчит наружу, компилятор может выкинуть с корнем её, все операции над ней и все её значения.

---

Переменная это уровень **языка**. Она абстрактна. У вас есть имя, тип и область видимости, определённые языком. Всё. А при сборке компилятор уже сам разберётся, как реализовать это, чтобы программа вела себя соответственно своему исходному коду. Чем меньше требований вы к переменной предъявляете, тем больше у компилятора свободы к самовыражению своей оптимизаторской сущности.

Однако, компиляторы обычно реализуют возможность сборки с *отладочной информацией*, нужной для осмотра состояния программы в любой момент с помощью отладчика. Там название переменной и её местонахождение указано. Но это удобство компилятора для разработки, а не особенность языка и, что интересно, *включение этого удобства может изменить реализацию переменной* (см. [опцию `/ZI` в MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx)).

Comment: Кажется я понял как работает ассемблер :D